# How to i add the this reference "System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" into Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add these reference, but how i don't know. Please anybody help to me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [`WPFToolkit`](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) from here

- Initially You need to add a reference to WPFToolkit.dll
  System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit